# "CatBoostError: wrong json type" when running predict on a loaded model

Tags: json, anaconda, runtime-error, catboost

We have a catboostClassifer model saved and loaded using default parameters. Model is saved in a Linux environment and loaded into Windows using Anaconda.

The following error is generated on predicting, after the model is loaded. Do you have any hint of what may be wrong?

```
CatBoostError: c:/program files (x86)/go agent/pipelines/buildmaster/catboost.git/catboost/private/libs/options/json_helper.h:112: Error: wrong json type

trace: \AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\anon-env\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in predict(self, data, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose)
   4011                   with log probability for every class for each object.
   4012         """
-> 4013         return self._predict(data, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose, 'predict')
   4014 
   4015     def predict_proba(self, data, ntree_start=0, ntree_end=0, thread_count=-1, verbose=None):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\anon-env\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in _predict(self, data, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose, parent_method_name)
   1876         self._validate_prediction_type(prediction_type)
   1877 
-> 1878         predictions = self._base_predict(data, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose)
   1879         return predictions[0] if data_is_single_object else predictions
   1880 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\anon-env\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in _base_predict(self, pool, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose)
   1273 
   1274     def _base_predict(self, pool, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose):
-> 1275         return self._object._base_predict(pool, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose)
   1276 
   1277     def _staged_predict_iterator(self, pool, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, eval_period, thread_count, verbose):

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._CatBoost._base_predict()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._CatBoost._base_predict()

CatBoostError: c:/program files (x86)/go agent/pipelines/buildmaster/catboost.git/catboost/private/libs/options/json_helper.h:112: Error: wrong json type
```